# Bootstrap loading button and ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, button, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a button change state on click and go back to normal on server response, here's my code:

```
            $(document).ready(function() { 
    var options2 = { 
        success:   processJson,  // post-submit callback 
        dataType:  'json',
        url:  'test.php?act=test'
    }; 
    $('#formProfileInfo').ajaxForm(options2);
    $('#save')
    .click(function () {
        var btn = $(this)
        btn.button('loading')
    }); 
function processJson(data)  { 
            if( data.status === 'success' ) {
                alert.success(data.message);
}
            if( data.status === 'error' ) {
                alert.error(data.message);
}
$('#save')
$(function() {
            btn.button('reset')
    });
}
        });
```

I'm using the [jQuery Form Plugin](http://malsup.com/jquery/form) for form submit via ajax.

The button is changing to loading stat but it's not resetting..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I've managed to get it to work by using:

```
$('#save').button('reset');
```

instead of:

```
$('#save')
$(function() {
            btn.button('reset')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you put `btn.button('reset')` up under the `processJson` function, after the success alert?

Comment: Not working, it's stopped the server from sending back success or error message. I think there's something wrong with the function.

Comment: Was it saving to the server properly before?

Comment: Yes the code above is saving to the server and the button state is changing to loading but it's not reverting back.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have a jquery selector for "save" id and after that you have no function applied over it:

```
$('#save')
$(function() {
            btn.button('reset')
    });
}
```

I don't think you need `$('#save')` or `$(function()` in order to reset the button